# How to declare variable inline in Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

How can I declare a variable inline in knockout? The way I have declared someValue is giving me error.

```
<input data-bind="textInput : new someValue ,event: {keypress: enterSearch}" class="form-control" placeholder="Jump to ...">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.selectPage.bind($data, someValue)"> Search! </button>
```

Comment: This seems like a wrong approach. Why are you trying to declare a variable in the HTML side?

Comment: Yes thats what I thought. How should i send the value input in the input field to the search event?

Comment: I have the property, $root.rootData.Page() in my view model as well. I want to set that property by that input box and send it to the  selectPage event.

Comment: you should have the input bound to an observable in your viewmodel, it will automatically get updated. and since the selectPage function is in the viewmodel, it already has access to the other observable. no need to pass it around

Comment: If i add an observable property, still i get nothing: That is my updated code.

Comment: <input data-bind="textInput : $root.rootData.Page()" class="form-control" placeholder="Jump to ...">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.selectPage.bind($data, $root.rootData.Page())"> Go! </button>

Comment: see my answer, you don't need to pass page() to your selectPage function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<input data-bind="value: page" class="form-control" placeholder="Jump to ...">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: selectPage"> Search! </button>
```

viewmodel (approx):

```
var viewmodel = function() {
  var page = ko.observable();

  var selectPage = function() {
    // just use page() here instead of passing it as a parameter

  };

  return {
    page: page,
    selectPage: selectPage
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the page, to make some calculations in my js.

Comment: you can keep the page() and selectPage() in that viewmodel, and if you need to call up to a root viewmodel, do it within the selectPage function

Comment: Everything is working fine, somehow the value is no updating after user inputs the value.

Comment: the value won't update until the input loses focus, if that's how you're inspecting/debugging

Comment: Yes even if the value loses focus, it is not updating

Comment: Here's a fiddle that demonstrates how the Page variable gets updated each time you change the text box (and lose focus) http://jsfiddle.net/xaq8rtx5/1/